# Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found, with proper extension installed

Tags: drivers, php, mongodb, composer-php

I have installed [recent MongoDB extension](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php) using PECL. My PHP version is 5.6, I am sure that the extension is running. I've also installed the Composer package running `composer require "mongodb/mongodb=^1.0.0"` in my project. The error message says: `in Client.php line 56: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found`, the `Client.php` file is one of the classes, supllied by the package. I am wondering, do I need to install any additional packages?